# Which Brahma beer is unhopped?

Tags: specialty-beers, buying, identification

I had a bottle of [Brahma](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_beer) beer when I was in Brasíl some years ago, and I didn't save the label.  These are what I remember:

- it was sweet and malty.
- it had a white label.
- it had 4% or thereabouts alcohol.
- I purchased it at a decent and reputable restaurant circa 2008 — so it most probably wasn't an old or even a mislabeled bottle.

Reading their [website](http://www.brahma.com.br/) is difficult for me, but I don't see anything which strikes me as a clear match — not even the Weiss (White) variety.  Possibly, I suppose, but I don't see anything in the description [here](http://www.brahma.com.br/cervejas/extra-weiss) which would obviate this question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it wasn't the Brahma Malzbier? I've had regular Brahma before and it taste like any other watery pale lager from MillBudCoors.

The Malzbier is a beer that is dark and they add caramel and it's low alcohol and sweet.

http://www.brahma.com.br/cervejas/malzbier

> Manufacture: American pale lager type beer in which, after filtration, caramel and sugar syrup are added, giving the dark coloration and **sweet** taste.

Comment: Could be.  I'll give it a try.